# Kelpie lookalike?

Tags: dogs, breeds

I like the look of the Australian kelpie and blue lacy breeds, however these dogs are working dogs and are not suited to family backyards. Is there a breed that somewhat looks like these but is a suitable family dog for small backyards?

Comment: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weimaraner](this) is like the blue lacy breed. Where are you located?

Answer (score 1):

Get yourself a mutt. No, seriously: a mixed-breed dog is probably the best option for a dog with the coat pattern of one breed and the temperament of another. The closer they are to purebred breeding programs, the closer they'll conform to the breed temperament, for better or for ill. Go to the shelter, look at dogs until you find one that's pretty enough, and see what they're like temperament-wise.

Answer (score 0):

I had a quick look with "Weimaraner alike breeds" in startpage.com, and found this resource, where someone had the same thinking like you: [weimaranerplanet.com](https://weimaranerplanet.com/which-dog-breed-is-similar-to-weimaraner/)

The author likes the look of the Weimaraner, and searches for a dog looking alike, but with less energy level. But as the author writes:

> I’m afraid I have bad news for you. If you’re looking for a couch potato or lower-energy pup that looks like a Weimaraner, there isn’t one as far as I can tell. But do let me know if you find one!